# sum of list of strings raises TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.5

Why does the following raise a `TypeError`? My list is type-homogeneous!

```
>>> a
['0', 'a']
>>> type(a[0])
<class 'str'>
>>> type(a[1])
<class 'str'>
>>> sum(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function takes a second argument - the initial accumulator value. When this is not provided, it is assumed to be 0. Thus, the first addition in your `sum(a)` is `0 + '0'`, producing the type error in question.

Instead you want:

```
a = ['0', 'a']
print(''.join(a)) # '0a'
```

If you try to use `sum` on strings, you will get an error saying to use `''.join(seq)` instead.

Comment: wow, I've only ever summed up ints, so I've never ran into this -- thanks!

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) start value cannot be a string.

Comment: great insight !

Comment: If you're summing strings, you should use `''.join(a)`, as noted in the docs for [**`sum`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

Comment: @PeterWood corrected, you flat out can't use it on strings